# Const argument in lambdas

Tags: c++, lambda

If I want to make a lambda of type `std::function<void(const Foo&)>`.
Why is it legal to drop the reference and the constness of the argument?
This is valid:

```cpp
std::function<void(const Foo&)> f = [](Foo) {
    // ...
};
```

Answer (score 8):

> If I want to make a lambda of type `std::function<void(const Foo&)>`

That type is not a lambda, so you cannot have a lambda of that type. I suppose that you mean, that you want to store a lambda in a function wrapper of that type.

> Why is it legal to drop the reference and the constness of the argument?

Because a `Foo` (the argument of the lambda) can be initialised from a `const Foo&` (the argument of the function wrapper). You can do this without a lambda as well:

```
const Foo& ref{some_value};
Foo f {ref};
```

Answer (score 1):

`std::function` works as long as the called function has parameters and return type that allow `std::function::operator()` to pass along its arguments. `std::function` isn't the lambda expression's type, it is a container that can store a lambda as well as other callables. Your original example works for the same reason this works:

```
void take_value(Foo) { }

void take_reference(const Foo& foo) {
  // fine, makes a copy while calling
  take_value(foo);
}
```

To illustrate the compatibility requirements of `std::function`, the following all work:

```
#include <functional>

int main() {
  // fine, can pass an int to function taking double
  std::function<void(int)> f1 = [] (double) { };

  // fine, just ignore the return
  std::function<void()> f2 = [] {return 1;};

  // fine, can return the int as a double
  std::function<double()> f3 = [] { return 1;};
}
```